# Why can I still write to /dev/null even after /dev is mounted read-only?

Tags: mount, devices, readonly, bind-mount

I was surprised to discover that I can still write to `/dev/null` even after remounting `/dev` to be read-only.

Here is a demonstration:

```
# echo foo > /dev/null
# echo foo > /dev/foo
# mount -o remount,ro /dev
# echo foo > /dev/null
# echo foo > /dev/foo
-bash: /dev/foo: Read-only file system
```

What is the reason for this?

(I guess one explanation could be that for some (all?) devices, the device is not part of the filesystem that links to the device.)

Are there any devices that are affected by `mount -o remount,ro`?  Or does `remount,ro` basically have no effect on devices in the specified filesystem?

Does anyone know where this behavior is documented?

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess: you're not actually modifying the filesystem by writing to `/dev/null`.

Device files are just a handle to point the kernel at a device with a major / minor number.  Indeed identical device files can exist on multiple file systems and they will refer to the same device.

So I imagine writing to them is not treated as writing to the file system.

Comment: Yes, if a read-only mounted root file system would prevent you from writing in `/dev` devices, nothing would work properly (including an interactive shell which write on a `/dev/ttyXX` file).

Answer (score 1):

When the kernel sees a write attempt to a device file it starts ignoring everything else (considering you are the root user and chattr hasn't been used).

IOW when you're working with the device file, you're *not* working with the underlying filesystem, you're working with the device file.

An attempt to modify the device file *itself*, i.e. rename/delete/update its timestamp, will fail.

Everything works as intended.

Comment: The kernel does check file permissions on a device file. This is why there are groups associated with devices sets. (audio, disk, floppy, tape…). You can try to change permissions on a `/dev/pts/X` file and check if you can open them.

Comment: The OP is working under the root user.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `W`rite permission on a directory controls ONLY file creation/deletion of files in that directory. To probably break your system, `sudo chmod a-w /dev/null`.
2. `/dev/null` is a pseudo
   device, which might not respect the `W` bit.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the write bit — as shown in the question, no `chmod` is involved, but the file system as a whole is remounted read-only.

Comment: @waltinator - Stephen Kitt is correct.  My question has nothing to do with the `w`rite permission on the file or directory (or device).  My question has to do with mounting the whole filesystem in read-only mode.  See `man 2 mount` for details.  Specifically, the `MS_RDONLY` mount flag.

Answer (score 0):

Device files are special files and work more or less like symlinks: Try the same (symlink in read-only fs linked to a file in rw fs) and editing of the file is also possible.